# How to optimize Memory leak in XML layout file

Tags: android, layout, memory-leaks

I have developed an android application and ran it on Nexus 5 device.
Analyzed the memory leak using Memory Analyzer tool in Android Studio and found that it uses 30+ MB memory. After commenting setContentView() from Oncreate() method from Activity Class shows there is a 10MB difference .

How to optimize the memory leak caused by the XML layout files?

Comment: do you have large images inside?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Comment: @Opiatefuchs; Yes, use only one background image, some edittext and a button

Comment: even if you just using one image, if it is too big it could cause this. And also overloaded xml layout could cause it..

Comment: Image size is 25 KB and it is not an overloaded XML file.